# How do you install a ceilng fan to an electrical box that has 1-black, 2-white, 2-green?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I want to install a ceiling fan to a ceiling fixture that has been unused all this time.

The ceiling fan has 1 blue, 1 black, 1 white and 1 green wire.

[image: ceiling fan]

The instructions indicate that I connect the green to green, white to white, and the blue+black to black.

However, when I opened the electrical box I found that there is 1 black, 2 white and 2 green cables.

[image: outlet box]

So how do I proceed in this scenario?

Thank you

Comment: How was the previous fixture wired?

Comment: This is a recently built apartment and there was no previous fixture. It was an unused box until now. So how you see it in the photo is I saw them for the first time when I removed the cover and pulled the wires out for a look.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter/voltmeter?

Comment: I do not, but I have a pig tail electrical tester that just has a bulb at the end.

Comment: Was there anything installed there, or just a blank cover?  Are there any wires stuffed back in the box?

Comment: Just a blank plastic cover. Aside from the wires I pulled out, there's nothing else in there that I can physically see that I can pull out. All wires run into their respective holes. Except for the 2 greens. 1 green runs into a hole while the other green is connected to the electrical box with a screw.

Comment: Where does the other white go? How many cables come into the box? (Romex, not individual wires) Do you know how many switches control this box?

Comment: 1 switch controls this box. While the 2 white is twisted together, they split off. One go into 1 hole and the other going into another hole opposite it.